# Does MikroORM support lazy loading?

Tags: typescript, orm, lazy-loading, micro-orm

Does MikroORM support lazy loading by default in the same way as the various ORMs do in Java or .NET (eg JPA/Hibernate, Entity Framework or NHibernate)